# Discord js slash command registered in code not showing in discord's command ui

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot with the new slash commands. I registered a simple ping command in the code, the bot was invited to the server with admin privileges. But in the ui the ping command I registered isn't being shown. Below is the code, Please lemme know if you need any furthur context regarding the situation.

```
import "dotenv/config";

import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, SlashCommandBuilder } from "discord.js";

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Bot is ready!");

  const ping = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")
    .setDescription("Using this command will ping!");

  client.application.commands
    .create(ping)
    .then(() => console.log("Done registering commands"))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  const isSelfMessaged = message.author.id === client.user.id;
  if (isSelfMessaged) return;

  message.reply("Hello there!");
});

client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
  if (interaction.commandName === "ping") {
    interaction.channel.send(`Pong! ${interaction.user}`);
  }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I was trying to register some slash commands, expected them to be shown in ui as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZawV.png)

Fredbot's commands are being shown but not my bots command.

Comment: Anyone correct me if I'm wrong, but according to the Discord.js documentation, you should be importing this as well: `PermissionFlagsBits`. For example: `const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');` (Straight from the Discord.js documentation here: https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/permissions.html#member-permissions I'm not 100% sure if that's your issue as your code seems like it should work, but try that and let us know if that helps or not.

Comment: Also, ps, you can shorthand checking if the message came from *any* bot by using `if (message.author.bot) return;` However it looks like you're checking if the message is coming from your specific bot itself. In that case you can still shorthand *that* like this: `if (message.author.id === client.user.id) return;`

Comment: The importing PermissionsFlagsBits didn't really work.

Comment: And also yea, you're right about the message thing, I was just checking if bot was responding at all or not so I quickly wrote a message check which won't loop

Comment: Are you getting any errors in  your console?

Comment: There aren't any errors code runs just fine. Thats what confuses me the most. Some other posts I saw had permissions related errors but in my case given admin privileges are there I don't think that should be a problem?

Comment: @Rishabh Have you tried registering them as guild commands instead of application commands? I know that, due to some API limitations, updating application commands can take up to an hour (or longer, not sure about the exact timeframe). Guild commands should update almost instantly.

Comment: Limiting the command to guild worked! I'm still not sure about the global ones so I'll put a comment if it comes live after a while. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: @Rishabh Posted as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77765045/10894961)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the command as a guild command. This will ensure that the commands are updated instantly for the specified guild(s). Application commands can take up to an hour (or longer, I'm not sure about the exact timeframe) to update due to API limitations.